# Can not make containers communicate despite being in the same network

Tags: asp.net-core, redis, docker-compose, docker-network

Hello i am trying to make a `.NET Core`server communicate with a `Redis` database.The server works well outside of the container.
The containers are set up.I can access the database using the host-port mapping .
However when i am doing an operation that requires the server to call the database the connection gets refused.

**dockercompose**

```
version: '3.3'
    services:
           db:
              image: redis:4.0.5-alpine
              container_name: redis0
              networks:
                - redis-net
              ports:
                - 6381:6379   //i can acess redis from the hostmachine via 6381  but i can't acess it via 6379 from the container with the server

            backend:
              image: server
              container_name: server0
              build: ./Server
              command: ["dotnet","Server.dll"]
              ports:
                - 9400:9300
              networks:
                - redis-net
              environment:
                - dbport=6379
              depends_on:
                - db

        networks:
            redis-net:
```

**Startup**

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

            services.AddOptions();
            services.AddMvc();

    try {
            var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables();
            var portStr = env["dbport"].ToString();
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText("dock.txt",$"dbport:{portStr}");
            if (!(int.TryParse(portStr,out int redisPort))) {
                return;
            }

            var mux = new Multiplexer();
            var logicalConnection = mux.OpenLink(redius.Address.Create(redisPort));
            services.AddSingleton(logicalConnection);

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            Console.WriteLine("Could not open link, ex:" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

For debugging i am writing the `exception` that the server throws inside a file in the container and i look it up using `docker exec -it <container_id> bash`

**Controller Method that throws**

```
 public async Task<List<User>> GetUsers()
        {
            try
            {
                var usersRaw = await this.connection.HMGetAllAsync("users");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(Constants.OUTPUT,ex.Message);
                return null;
            }
            return null;

        }
```

The error says : `connection refused for 127.0.0.1:6379`.Is the `ip` address wrong? Basically the problem is the following:

```
                Redis    Server
HostPort        6381     9400
ContainerPort   6379     9300
AppPort         6379     9300
```

I can acess Redis from outside via `6381` and i can also acess `Server` via `9400`.
Server can communicate with a `Redis` both outside containers (so no proprietary library fault).
Can not access `Redis` from the `Server` via `6379` (both being in the `network` -> `redis-net`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the error message, it seems you are using `localhost:6379` from `server image`.

Try base url with `http://redis0:6379` or `http://db:6379`

Comment: I am indeed using `localhost` when calling the `database` from the server.This is something i was worried about.What is the name of the host by convention when there are lets say `2` containers in a `network` (both on localhost)   ?

Comment: For `hostname`, you could use `container_name` or the service name. Can you access the database container with above ways?

Comment: I am still getting connection refused when calling from the server using  port `6379`. And i can still access it from outside via `6381`.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian What is the full connection you used?

Comment: It worked ,it was actually a server problem ,the connection was established though using the container name as hostname.